# How to prevent CSS and JS to load if Adblock is detected?

Tags: javascript, css, adblock

Recently I came across a website that sells adds ( http://buysellads.com/ ) on a friends computer with Adblock enabled and the site seems to detect the browser add-on and it disables the CSS and JS.

I have been trying to read their code, but I can not seem to find the line that makes this happen. I know there are ways to detect and give the user a message to disable the plugin, but I find this way to be more clever.

I appreciate if somebody knows or finds the code that triggers and executes.

Bonus question: How would this work with a cache plugin like W3 Total Cache for Wordpress? I make this question because I wonder how the website would look after the person whitelisted the page and the site refreshes. In theory it should display the CSS and JS because Adblock is not found, but I am not sure if cache plugins would break that and display the site as it looked before without any CSS or JS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry my main language is not english. Is this a joke?

Comment: You could try disabling javascript in your the browser and see if it still disabled CSS. If not then, .. u know the rest :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how this particular site does it, but one possibility is to add/load the JS and CSS files via an ad serving system that is blocked by Adblock (load the style and script tags in an ad placement).

Depending on how Adblock works, it could be enough to host the files on a subdomain like ads.your-domain.com or banner.your-domain.com.

You could then set display=none with inline style on a wrapper containing the whole page, and display=block on an element outside the wrapper, containing the message to the user. The CSS file loaded via an ad serving system could then change the display properties of the two elements (so the users without Adblock gets the content of the page and not the message).